# Setting parameter of other connection

Tags: postgresql, configuration, parameter

I can set `log_statement` parameter to `'all'` on the current connection. I want to do it for a few other connections on my database that are controlled by a connected web application. I know that I can execute `alter database my_db set log_statement = 'all'`, but it will take effect after the application restart. Is it possible to switch that parameter on behalf of an application connections without restarting it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set a parameter for a different session.

You could attach to the backend process with a debugger and change the global variable (12345 is the process ID):

```
gdb /path/to/postgres 12345
...
(gdb) set var log_statement=3
(gdb) detach
Detaching from program: /path/to/postgres, process 12345
[Inferior 1 (process 12345) detached]
(gdb) quit
```

But I guess that is not a good solution for you.

Other than that setting the parameter on the database level (`ALTER DATABASE`) or user level (`ALTER ROLE`) are the only options.

Answer (score 0):

If you send a `SIGHUP` signal to a specific backend process, rather than to the main postgres process, only that backend will reread the configuration files.

```
postgres=# select pg_backend_pid();
 pg_backend_pid 
----------------
          16962
(1 row)

postgres=# show log_statement;
 log_statement 
---------------
 none
(1 row)

postgres=# alter system  set log_statement to 'all';
ALTER SYSTEM

#run "kill -HUP 16962" from another console

postgres=# show log_statement;
 log_statement 
---------------
 all
(1 row)

postgres=# alter system  reset log_statement;
ALTER SYSTEM
```